# Adding weights to shapefile for points in ArcGIS Pro using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-pro

I have a .csv file with longitude, latitude representing a point on map. And another column that I will use as weights for these maps. I want to calculate weighted mean center for all the points using ArcPy.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import arcpy


df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
longs = df['Longitude'].tolist()
lats = df['Latitude'].tolist()
wts = df['Weights'].tolist()
point = arcpy.Point()
pointGeoms = []

for idx in range(len(longs)):
    point.X = float(lats[idx])
    point.Y = float(longs[idx])
    point.M = int(wts[idx])
    pointGeoms.append(arcpy.PointGeometry(point))
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management (pointGeoms,"centroids.shp")
```

Above code is for generating shapefile. Below code is for calculating weighted means.

```
import arcpy


workspace = r"C:\Users\sam"
input_FC = "centroids.shp"
weight_field = "M"

try:
    # Set the workspace to avoid having to type out full path names
    arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
    # Process: Mean Center...
    arcpy.MeanCenter_stats(input_FC, MEAN_output, "#", "#", "#")

except:
    # If an error occurred when running the tool, print out the error message.
    print(arcpy.GetMessages())
```

I am not able to get any positive outcomes from both the codes. The shapefile generated by first code shows empty point values in ArcGIS Pro. And the second code generates a point randomly placed very far away from any point of interest.

Comment: You mention ArcGIS Pro but do not have a tag for that, and do have a tag for ArcMap which you do not mention.  It may not matter but which architecture are you using?

Comment: Hi, I am using ArcGIS Pro Desktop. There was no tag for ARCGIS Pro when I added this question.

Comment: It's the ArcGIS Pro application of ArcGIS Desktop, and there has been an [tag:ArcGIS-pro] tag available for it since 16 May 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that latitude is actually the Y axis, so if you are entering the coordinates, it should be long, lat not lat, long. You should also create a weight field for the feature, not for the geometry.

This is a working example:

```
import arcpy

lats = [0, 1, 2]
longs = [1, 3, 4]
wts = [1, 3, 5000]

pointGeoms = []
feature_class = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(
    "in_memory", "tempfc", "POINT")[0]
arcpy.AddField_management(feature_class, "weight", "LONG")

with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(feature_class, ["weight", "SHAPE@XY"]) as cursor:
    for i in range(len(longs)):
        cursor.insertRow([wts[i], (longs[i], lats[i])])
try:
    arcpy.MeanCenter_stats(feature_class, 'c:\\temp\\mean.shp', "weight", "#", "#")

except:
    # If an error occurred when running the tool, print out the error message.
    print(arcpy.GetMessages())
```

Comment: Thank you, Lennert! Your working example is really helpful. On a parting note, do you know any good book/course that you'd recommend for learning ArcGIS Python programming?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I can't help you there, I learn everything via the arcpy documentation on esri and gis.stackexchange

Comment: @LennertDeFeyter I think you just gave the best resources on the subject. Particularly [gis.se].